# x86 GNU Assembler Strange Change Seg Fault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

The following x86 assembly code assembles fine, and it used to run flawlessly on my school's linux server, but when applying the same code to my linux virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04, all of a sudden it causes a segmentation fault.

Did stack conventions change, is this a GNU assembler problem? What memo did I miss?
I am running on a 64-bit machine, and this is a warm-up to building the backbone of an OS, so I need to be able to use the 16-bit real, 32-bit protected, and the 64-bit mode all in the same program. So I suppose what I really need is the little details about making all modes valid in the same program. I know to use .code16/32/64 when changing modes, but I guess what I'm missing (and can't seem to find in any OS tutorial, is how to do this on 64-bit architecture.

```
.code32
.text 
.global _start

_start:

    pushl $str1
    pushl $len1
    call print
    addl $8, %esp <-cleans up the stack pointer

exit:

    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

print:

    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx <- This is where the Seg Fault occurs according to GDB
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx
    int $0x80
    popl %ebp
    ret

.data

str1 : .ascii "String1\n"

len1 =  . - str1
```

Comment: Thanks Dark, I couldn't figure out how to fix the carriage return and line feeds from the linux code. Is there a simple trick for that?

Comment: There is a button for it on the formatting toolbar, or: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I don't understand the last edit of the question. A 64-bit thread will have a 64-bit stack, a 32-bit thread a 32-bit stack, and a 16-bit thread a 16-bit stack. You just cannot share stacks between these modes, so your current code will only work in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: Actually my current code will only work in a 32-bit environment. My now evolving problem and question is this: how do I assemble a boot-sector program which directs the CPU from its starting mode(16-bit real), to 32-bit mode where it recognizes the existence of all peripherals, and finally to 64-bit mode where all processes will be run?

Clearly this must be doable since that is how Operating Systems are made, but how do I do the transforms correctly in the span of one program containing the code for all modes?

Comment: @patrickjp93: Uf! I think that is clearly off-topic in this thread. You should really ask another question about this.

Comment: I realize it will likely entail a whole other question, but I do need a start here. I can't just omit the standard library (I think) when I have to traverse all the way up anyhow, so at the very least getting an answer to having a processor in 64-bit mode change to 32-bit mode will be helpful.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate the existing guides for this stuff only go up to the 32-bit level, and some even forget the facts of endianness differences between registers, RAM, and the Hard Disk/CD Drive. I have even searched for the boot code of Ubuntu, but I can find nothing lower than the kernel.

Comment: @patrickjp93: If you want to know about the boot code of Linux, by all means, ask about it. But please, do not add new questions in the comments, instead create a new question. Comments are to comment about the _current_ question. Remember that StackOverflow is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site.

Comment: I'm aware. I'm just trying to make my next question more useful/pointed so I don't wind up in the same problem I did here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a 64-bit machine, while your program is obviously 32-bit.

I have a 64-bit machine, if I compile it with this command, it fails, same line as you:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib test.s
```

However, if I compile a 32-bit executable:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -m32 test.s
```

And all is fine.

Note that you may need some packages to be able to compile a 32-bit program in a 64-bit machine (`g++-multilib` or whatever they call it these days).

Comment: I do have a 64-bit machine, but currently I'm in the midst of learning how to write a fully-functioning boot-sector program (building an OS skeleton for a class) and I need to be able to transfer between 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit modes without seg-faulting.

In other words, I do need the standard library EVENTUALLT, so I can't just compile the finished product without it (I don't think...). Is someone here an expert on the matter?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. This answers the immediate question - your code is 32-bit x86 assembly, so it needs to compiled targeting 32-bit x86 mode. If you need to write more code / port this to x64 mode, that would seem to be a different question. It is also very unlikely that you would want/be able to use any of the gcc startup or system library code when writing a boot-sector program.