# Why can't this assembly program run?

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I have a piece of code in a file named *cpuid.s*:

```
.code32
.section .data
output:
    .asciz "The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"
.section .bss
    .lcomm buffer, 12
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    movl $0, %eax
    cpuid
    movl $buffer, %edi
    movl %ebx, (%edi)
    movl %edx, 4(%edi)
    movl %ecx, 8(%edi)
    pushl $buffer
    pushl $output
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp
    pushl $0
    call exit
```

My OS type is 64-bit, so I add `.code32` to compile, and I use gcc on Ubuntu14.04 to compile this code:

```
gcc -o demo cpuid.s
```

And it is compiled successfully. Then I run demo on the terminal, but it prompts `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

So I use gdb to debug. Then gdb prompts:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__printf (format=0x601078 <buffer> "GenuineIntel") at printf.c:28
28  printf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Please indicate me what is the problem and how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Add -m32 to your gcc command line.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths So how to solve it?

Comment: The `.code32` is incorrect! You cannot run 32 bit code in a 64 bit process. You can force the assembler to generate 32 bit assembly with `.code32`, but that doesn't make it run. As Jonathon Reinhart already said, you need to assembly the file as a 32 bit source file for this to work.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: It's in the BSS, so it's already initialized to zero.  It may already be followed by zeroed bytes, but should be fixed.  It's not sufficient on its own, because the missing `-m32` is obviously a critical problem, well spotted by Jonathon.  Why are people upvoting this?  It's just a "forgot `-m32` when writing 32bit code", and some other asm-learner bugs.

Comment: @PeterCordes : fair point. Question seems to have changed beyond recognition, and now suffers from calling convention issues.

Comment: So if the file is named `cpuid.s` (weird name, btw), why are you compiling `test.s`?

Comment: What happened to my comment about the buffer size being too small to hold a trailing zero-byte?  How did that get deleted when the OP modified the question to only ask about the more serious `-m32` problem (which had already been solved in comments)?  I didn't delete it myself.  @unwind: the edit history shows why he's talking about `cpuid.s`.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths The main problem is that OP compiles 32 bit code as 64 bit.

Comment: @FUZxxl : in the original question, yes. Not any more, though.

Comment: @FUZxxl  Thanks, FUZxxl. I have solve how to write 32 bit assembly in 64 bit mode with your help. But if I change my code from 32 bit mode to 64 bit mode, I got the other problem, the details are shown in the question editted just now.

Comment: From now on, *please do not drastically change the question*. You were originally assembling 32-bit code. If you changed that code to 64-bit and are having trouble, then *please open a new question*. Recall that Stack Overflow is only 10% about helping *you*. The other 90% is about helping others in the future. If you change your question, you might feel satisfied, but the Q&A is left as an discontinuous mess.

Comment: OP, I've rolled back your question to the last version that illustrated the original problem. Please do not drastically alter your questions. If you have a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: His edited question (just `push` / `call printf` / `push` / `call exit`) was still valid 32bit code, and the right answer was still to compile it with `-m32`.  It didn't pop the stack after calling `printf`, but that didn't matter since `exit` doesn't return.  So you're right that he shouldn't change the question, but IMO he just simplified the question to what was really the major problem.  (Although it had already been answered in comments, and is a duplicate of many previous questions with the same mistake).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mostly too trivial (just the `-m32` thing) and is now a confusing mess for anyone who stumbles onto it in the future.

Comment: @PeterCordes “trivial” is not a valid closing reasons. In retrospect, this might be obvious, but to OP it isn't. Can you name one of the “many previous questions with the same mistake” so I can close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @FUZxxl: "Not useful" is a valid downvote reason, if not a close reason.  I tried to search, but `-m32` doesn't work as a search term.  It took ages to find one where `-m32` was the answer, and not just part of the question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938907/x86-gnu-assembler-strange-change-seg-fault is one such Q&A

Comment: @PeterCordes Try `m32`. The hyphen negates the search term.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I used google, and put `"-m32"` in quotes, and also searched on assembly and segfault.  Otherwise I'd get tons of hits about people trying to build 32bit libs or C programs, rather than asm programs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Any way, thank you for looking up that duplicate. Let's leave this as a signpost so perhaps more people are directed towards the original question.

Answer (score 2):

In a 64 bit (amd64) process, only 64 bit code can run. The `.code32` directive forces the assembler to assembly your instructions as 32 bit code, but it doesn't make that magically work. Instead, the processor, still being in 64 bit mode, interprets your 32 bit machine code as 64 bit machine code with typically catastrophic results.

If you want to write 32 bit assembly, you need to compile your whole program as a 32 bit program. This causes Linux to set the processor to 32 bit compatibility mode for your program so the 32 bit code runs fine. With gcc, this can be done by passing `-m32` to the compiler at all stages of compilation. In your current example, simply remove the `.code32` directive and then compile with

```
gcc -m32 -o demo test.s
```

Comment: Thanks, FUZxxl. I have solve how to write 32 bit assembly in 64 bit mode with your help. But if I change my code from 32 bit mode to 64 bit mode, I got the other problem, the details are shown in the question editted just now.

Comment: @leohotfn You cannot just change `esp` to `rsp` and expect the code to work in 64 bit mode. Many details are different such as the calling convention.

Comment: OK, thanks very very much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key point to take away here is this:

**The "bitness" of your executable (ELF) file, and the "bitness" of the machine code GAS is emitting are *independent*.**

As FUZxxl mentioned, `.code32` tells GAS to emit 32-bit machine code. However, GCC (driving GAS) is ultimately producing a *64-bit* ELF file.

When you execute this program, the kernel says "This is a 64-bit ELF, I will run it in 64-bit mode." That of course doesn't end well when the CPU (in 64-bit mode) tries to execute your 32-bit instructions.

Adding `-m32` (as mentioned in the comments) tells GCC to do two things:

- Produce a 32-bit ELF file
- Link against 32-bit `libc`
- Include 32-bit C startup code